# ssh-keygen on yubikey gives FIDO_ERR_PIN_AUTH_BLOCKED

Tags: ssh, yubico, yubikey

```
ssh-keygen -vvvv -t ecdsa-sk -O resident
Generating public/private ecdsa-sk key pair.
You may need to touch your authenticator to authorize key generation.
Enter PIN for authenticator: 
debug3: start_helper: started pid=16581
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 5
debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
debug1: start_helper: starting /usr/lib/openssh/ssh-sk-helper 
debug1: sshsk_enroll: provider "internal", device "(null)", application "ssh:", userid "(null)", flags 0x21, challenge len 0 with-pin
debug1: sshsk_enroll: using random challenge
debug1: sk_probe: 1 device(s) detected
debug1: sk_probe: selecting sk by touch
debug1: ssh_sk_enroll: using device /dev/hidraw2
debug1: ssh_sk_enroll: fido_dev_make_cred: FIDO_ERR_PIN_AUTH_BLOCKED
debug1: sshsk_enroll: provider "internal" returned failure -1
debug1: ssh-sk-helper: Enrollment failed: invalid format
debug1: ssh-sk-helper: reply len 8
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 5
debug1: client_converse: helper returned error -4
debug3: reap_helper: pid=16581
Key enrollment failed: invalid format
```

No one had this error on Google, or at least there are no solutions for that.

What is happening? My yubikey is plugged and I tried to touch it or put the PIN

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message. Reason was that my yubikey did not have a PIN set. After setting a PIN for the yubikey with

`ykman fido access change-pin`

I could create residential ssh keys.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar issue but with the debug error FIDO_ERR_PIN_NOT_SET. And that was due to the fact that my FIDO2 pin wasn't set in the Yubikey manager (Applications -> FIDO2)...

So I would assume that your error is due to a locked pin somehow. I would try to change the FIDO2 PIN and/or reset it completely if I were you.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue, error was `Key enrollment failed: invalid format`. I fixed it (on Manjaro) by installing newer version of `libfido2` (version 1.12.0-5) and upgrading system, and then this worked:

```
ssh-keygen -O no-touch-required -t ecdsa-sk -vvv
```

It printed some info about codes, which was different then previous ones, and I am able to use this key.